# Data types and query speed

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Does the type of data has an impact on the speed of queries. How important is to use correct types like smallint instedof int or even tinyint in tables which has small amount of rows.

Does query

```
select * from table
```

will be faster for tinyint than for int ??

Comment: With small amount of rows it would probably make no difference, when you get to millions, the difference in the data size might have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

It can affect performance, for example, the smaller data size the quicker you can get them, the less pages they reqire on disk. So you have to try to choose type of smallest possible size.

Answer (score 0):

You can't differentiate the two datatypes:`TINYINT` and `INT` with speed nor optimize because they are all numbers. They only differ on their `SIZE`s.

Comment: Yes I knwo that they got diffrent size but is size matters ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know **all** query results in PostgreSQL are sent from the server to the client in **text** form (e.g. if you have an `INTEGER` column, the value from that column will be coverted to text before sending it to you). There is an option of sending the binary form but it is officially discouraged and not so well documented (in the PostgreSQL API). I'm pretty sure that most clients built on libpq/so/dll (and friends) use the text form.

Having said that I think that it really matters only **on the server side** (for PostgreSQL), for both storage and query efficiency. Unfortunately I'm not PostgreSQL developer, so I canot give you more infotmation about the server side. I did quite a lot programming on the client side (using PostgreSQL and MySQL API).

MySQL API sends everything in binary, so it may matter a bit more on the client side.

And as always .... size matters :)